# Why doesn't my asp.net application listen to https://localhost:5001?

Tags: asp.net-core, https, kestrel-http-server

I'm developing a web api, but when I run it with dotnet on Ubuntu18.04, it only listens on http://localhost:5000.
I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy and to redirect http to https, but I think that the problem is with kestrel.

Answer (score -1):

Say you want to listen port 5020

```
 var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
         :
        .UseUrls("http://localhost:5020/")
        .Build();
    host.Run();
```